# How do I specify 'all td, and all td img' in a CSS selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, x-ray

I am using the X-ray JS package to scrape a table from a page. Desired tags and attributes are specified using an array of CSS selectors in a JSON string.

`"{[ 'th, td' ]}"` correctly gets content from all `th` and `td` tags.

I additionally need the `img` tags within `td` so I capture icons.

What selectors string would do that?

See https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray

Answer (score 2):

For selecting the `img` tags within a `td`, the CSS selector would be `td img`.

```css
th, td, td img {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
td img {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1' />
    </td>
    <td>Some description</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/2' />
    </td>
    <td>Some description</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, for X-ray you'd probably need to write it as follows: (based on what is mentioned in question for th, td)

```
{[ 'th, td, td img' ]}
```

Comment: Since `th` is present in the rules, if there can be an `img` inside a `th`, you need to add `th img`

Comment: @LGSon: True, but question said *select all img within td* so I excluded it :)

Comment: @LGSon That's OK, you reminded me to check but my `th` tags don't have `img`. I will test this in Xray when I get a chance.

Comment: @Harry Thanks - looks right to me. Also thanks for formatting my question, I was struggling on my phone.

Comment: @Harry Just flag these comments as obsolete when you are all done